# Do you lose all history of your completed challenges when you do a prestige reset?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

When you do a prestige reset do you lose all history of your completed challenges? Do you get to re-do challenges for points?

I'm interested in both knowing what challenges I have completed or not completed in my entire career, and whether I'll be able to get the points for them again when I go prestige.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you prestige all of your completed challenges (except lifetime/career challenges) are reset.  There is no history of completed challenges, and you literally start from scratch.  All challenges will pay out again when completed (both experience and money) and a special 'prestige' challenge category is opened up.

Here is a list of [what you keep/lose when you prestige](http://www.gamespot.com/xbox360/action/callofduty7workingtitle/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-57223881&pid=960189)

Comment: Don't the career challenges stay between prestiges?

Comment: I was just looking the name of those challenges up :)  Added to the answer

Comment: that's a shame. =( cool for the getting the points over again, ick for the losing track of what you have completed.

Comment: added a link to a sticky on GameSpot that sums it up nicely

Comment: The Prestige playlist becomes available.  There is not a special prestige challenge category for this game.